# What is Delphine Talking About?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

While [Sven the bard](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sven) is playing at the [Sleeping Giant Inn](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sleeping_Giant_Inn) in [Riverwood](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Riverwood), you may occasionally here a discussion between himself and [Delphine](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Delphine) (prior to the quest [Alduin's Wall](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alduin%27s_Wall)) that goes like the following:

> **Delphine**: "Sven, we need to talk..."
>   **Sven**: "Here we go..."
>   **Delphine**: "It's about your singing. Well, not your singing, your songs. *But you know what I'm talking about*."
>   **Sven**: "You do realize these simpletons
>   wouldn't know real music if it bit them in the britches, hmm? Very
>   well. Your wish is my command."
>   **Delphine**: "Wonderful. And let's not
>   have this chat again next week. Agreed?"

I emphasise the line from Delphine; *But you know what I'm talking about*. **What IS she talking about?**

Based on the response from Sven is implies she feels the locals dislike the song choice, however the songs he plays are no different to any other bard in Skyrim ([Ragnar the Red](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bardic_Performances#Ragnar_the_Red), [The Age of Aggression](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bardic_Performances#The_Age_of_Aggression) and [Tale of the Tongues](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bardic_Performances#Tale_of_the_Tongues)). Plus this discussion is had when Whiterun hold remains neutral in the war and "The Age of Aggression" is the political song of choice, so it can't be that his songs are anti-Imperial rule, not that she even cares that much about the war, though I don't imagine she would support the Stormcloaks.

I also don't think any of the songs are disruptive of her secret identity or overly difficult to understand for the local *simpletons*.

So, again; **What is she talking about?**

Comment: Hmm, doesn't he also sign [The Dragonborn Comes](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bardic_Performances#The_Dragonborn_Comes)?  I think that song makes her nervous.

Comment: @Nelson Not according to [this](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bardic_Performances) Wiki page.

Comment: Maybe he sings it when you're not there, that's why Delphine had these "talks"  :)

Comment: There is no real reason other than to picture Delphine as bossy. This is about building Delphine's character rather than the songs Sven are singing.

Comment: @xrogaan Interesting, perhaps I need to explore beyond the fourth wall every once in a while. I guess my curiosity got the better of me. Why not write that as an answer and, if nothing more conclusive comes up, I'll mark it.

Comment: @KallumTanton Because it is not an answer; I don't have sources. The interaction between Delphine and Sven never expanded beyond that exchange. I'm just throwing a guess, taking the position of the developer and what they wanted to achieve. Skyrim is incredibly lazy at world building, which is why I think my point of view is the right one as it is the simplest one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this conversation is about the Age of Aggression song.

> I don't imagine she would support the Stormcloaks.

She might not support the Stormcloaks, but some of the townsfolk definitely do, which explains why she wouldn't like the song being played there.

For example if after the intro of the game you decide to follow Ralof (a Stormcloak soldier) to Riverwood you get to hear a [conversation](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Gerdur#Conversations) that he has with his sister Gerdur, brother-in-law Hod and nephew Frodnar, from which becomes clear that this family is not very fond of Imperials.

As small towns with few families usually share similar opinions I think a song that contains the text "*down with Ulfric*" is generally disliked here.

Comment: I agree with that - doesn't matter what she is supporting, Sven singing anit-Stormcloak song would make less people coming to her inn

Answer (score -3):

I think that Sven was perhaps meant to be singing a song about the Blades, but in the game script it doesn't appear. Perhaps that could be it.